# Why does my CSS not work when I pass two parameters to app.get?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, express

I'm creating an express app and my CSS code stops working whenever i add an ":ID" parameter to the URL.  I know it's a filepath issue because bootstrap still comes in fine, but on the page with the ID parameter it shows this: "Refused to apply style from 'https://XXXXXX.c9users.io/unapproved/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled."

main.css is in my /public folder, but it looks like it's looking in a folder titled "unapproved".

I've tried changing the routing order, i've tried changing my app.use(express.static(__dirname)) code.

here's my app.get:

```
app.get("/unapproved/:id/", function(req, res){
    var invoiceID = mongoose.mongo.ObjectId(req.params.id);
    InvoiceObj.findById(invoiceID,function(err,foundInvoice){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            res.render("invoiceScreen",{invoice:foundInvoice});
        }
    });
```

here's my html:

```
<% include partials/header %>
<h1><image src="<%= invoice.imageUrl %>"</h1>
<% include partials/footer %>
```

here's my header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Invoice system</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js'></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
```

Comment: `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"))` ?

Comment: What is app.get? You need to tag this.

Answer (score 2):

I think change to css path absolute path will solve your problem

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css">
```

Comment: This worked for me.  I changed it in the header file and it worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of situation, it's better to use `virtual path` for your static files because relative path doens't work very well; like:

Assuming folder structure:

```
app.js
public
|  +-- main.css
```

```
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + "/public"))
```

And in you `html`, make path absolute

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/main.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using ./ or ../ before your assest(images / css / js ) for example.
./css/style.css or css/bootstrap.css ../images/example.png

you can use / for example
**/css/style.css** or **/css/bootraps.css** **/images/example.png**

/ will tell your app to look from root dir.